# Can a forward slash at the end of a url effect the pages formatting?

Tags: php, url, include

I have an `.htaccess` file that redirects all pages to `index.php`.

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php    
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];    
$url_array=explode("/",$url);   
array_shift($url_array);   
$url = $url_array[0].'.php';
include($url_array[0].'.php');
?>
```

This page takes all incoming url's that are formatted as `www.sitename.com/profile/01234` and stores each part in a separate row of an array. the first row (`$url_array[0]`) is the name of the page (profile) and gets put in the include statement.

When I go to `www.sitename.com/profile` it includes "profile.php" perfectly but as soon as I add a **`/`** or **`/01234`** then the formatting of "profile.php" gets all messed up.

I've used `print_r($url_array);` to check the array and everything looks fine.

```
Array ( [0] => people [1] => 01234 )
```

I've spent hours trying to figure out how a **`/`** at the end of the url would effect the layout/stylesheet of the included file but without any success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF your browser thinks you are at `www.sitename.com/profile/01234` and tries to load a css stylesheet or js file, for example `src='style.css'`, your browser will try to load `www.sitename.com/profile/style.css`.  What you want to do is tell the browser to always look for that file at the root of your domain by making your css/js sources `src='/style.css'`.  This way, it is always relative to your root path.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to relative `ccs` paths in your html, adding the last `/` leads to none existing `css` paths to be generated.